Use the Django admin site query language with a SQL Server backend?
When going to any model I tried to use the DjangoQL search syntax to query something like field = "fieldvalue".
If I use SQLite as the backend this works fine if I use SQL Server it errors out saying query object has no attribute explain_format.
My settings.py for the database
ENGINE 'mssql'
HOST my_host
NAME my_name

and the options are
driver: ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server 
host_is_server: True

I am successfully able to connect to the server, for example using python manage.py shell I can query tables etc. The error only appears when using the admin page.
Any ideas what might be going on.
PS I needed to use host_is_server otherwise it wasn't working, not sure why
settings.py:
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'mssql',
        'HOST': my_host,
        'NAME': my_name,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
            'host_is_server': True,
        }
    }
}

main/models.py
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=255)
    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=['name'],
                condition=models.Q(name__isnull=False),
                name='non_null_name_unique',
            ),
        ]

main/admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from djangoql.admin import DjangoQLSearchMixin

class MyModelAdmin(DjangoQLSearchMixin, admin.modelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['name']
    list_display = ['name']

admin.site.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin) 


Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8100/admin/main/mymodel/?q-l=on&q=name+%3D+%22Test%22

Django Version: 4.2.15
Python Version: 3.10.11
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'rest_framework',
 'djangoql',
 'nested_admin',
 'import_export',
 'django_filters',
 'authentication',
 'common',
 'main']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\UserPath\.venv\django\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\UserPath\.venv\django\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\UserPath\.venv\django\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 688, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\UserPath\.venv\django\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 134, in _wrapper_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\UserPath\.venv\django\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 62, in _wrapper_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\UserPath\.venv\django\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 242, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\UserPath\.venv\django\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 46, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\UserPath\.venv\django\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 134, in _wrapper_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\UserPath\.venv\django\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 1926, in changelist_view
    cl = self.get_changelist_instance(request)
  File "C:\Users\UserPath\.venv\django\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 836, in get_changelist_instance
    return ChangeList(
  File "C:\Users\UserPath\.venv\django\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\views\main.py", line 122, in __init__
    self.queryset = self.get_queryset(request)
  File "C:\Users\UserPath\.venv\django\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\views\main.py", line 529, in get_queryset
    qs, search_may_have_duplicates = self.model_admin.get_search_results(
  File "C:\Users\UserPath\.venv\django\lib\site-packages\djangoql\admin.py", line 93, in get_search_results
    explain()
  File "C:\Users\UserPath\.venv\django\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1281, in explain
    return self.query.explain(using=self.db, format=format, **options)
  File "C:\Users\UserPath\.venv\django\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 610, in explain
    return "\n".join(compiler.explain_query())
  File "C:\Users\UserPath\.venv\django\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1611, in explain_query
    result = list(self.execute_sql())
  File "C:\Users\UserPath\.venv\django\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1549, in execute_sql
    sql, params = self.as_sql()
  File "C:\Users\UserPath\.venv\django\lib\site-packages\mssql\compiler.py", line 366, in as_sql
    self.query.explain_format,

Exception Type: AttributeError at /admin/main/mymodel/
Exception Value: 'Query' object has no attribute 'explain_format'

just running something like name = "Test" in the query in the admin site will fail. The library I'm using is pymssql and mssql-django (https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-django)

Please provide a [mre], share the query you're trying to run, the complete error traceback and any other relevant code that you have. Also specify the exact package you're using for the SQL Server backend with Django (Since it's not a builtin backend).

i tried to provide a larger example

Please share the complete error traceback. It's important debugging information.

let me know if there is something missing there that would help

Any clues at AttributeError: 'Query' object has no attribute 'explain_query'?

I think there's a bug in mssql-django, the self.query.explain_format here probably needs to be either self.query.explain_info.format or explain.format (I am not sure), you should probably raise a bug on their end.
